# MS SQL - Trying to use FOR JSON to output with square brackets for each value

Tags: sql, arrays, json, sql-server

I am using MSSQL to try to get a JSON output in a specific format, with square brackets around individual values. Here is part of the query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
    (SELECT Email_Address AS fieldValues
     FROM table1
     FOR JSON PATH) records
FROM table1
FOR JSON PATH, WITHOUT_ARRAY_WRAPPER
```

This is the result:

```
{
    "records": [
        {
            "fieldValues": "test@email.com"
        }
    ]
}
```

I need to have square brackets around the email address so it looks like this:

```
{
    "records": [
        {
            "fieldValues": [
                 "test@email.com"
             ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Serializing of JSON arrays in SQL server is a little bit cumbersome and requires things like using [JSON_QUERY()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/json-query-transact-sql) over [STRING_AGG()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-agg-transact-sql) output, e.g.:

```sql
select
  (
    select
      json_query('['+(
        select string_agg(quotename(Email_Address, '"'), ',')
        from table1
      )+']', '$') as [fieldValues]
      for json path
  ) as [records]
for json path, without_array_wrapper;
```

Comment: This is very helpful, thank you! Would it be possible to have each email address prefixed with fieldValues and its own curly braces? Like this:

`{
    "records": [
        {
            "fieldValues": [
                 "test1@email.com"
             ]
        },
        {
            "fieldValues": [
                 "test2@email.com"
             ]
        },
        {
            "fieldValues": [
                 "test3@email.com"
             ]
        }
    ]
}`